# Missing something with strictness

Tags: haskell, strictness

I have this code:

```
divisors n = 1:[y|y<-[2..(n `div` 2)], n `mod` y == 0]

writeList l = do print "Start"
                 print l
```

Then, i want to call the function with strict argument; i tried:

```
writeList $! (divisors 12345678)
```

and

```
(divisors 12345678) \`seq\` (writeList (divisors 12345678))
```

But it does not behave as if it has strict argument: i.e. after the "Start" I have to wait for the evaluation of `(divisors 12345678)`

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the difference between whnf and nf.

Comment: Also, using `seq` (or `deepseq`) like that will just throw away the result of evaluating the first argument. You need to introduce explicit sharing, e.g. ```let ds = divisors 12345678 in ds `seq` writeList ds```.

Comment: @hamar: thank you for your help. Is `writeList $!! (divisors 12345678)` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq`(or `$!`) evalueates only for first head normal form, a `(:)` constructor in your case, you can use [deepseq](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/deepseq-1.3.0.0/Control-DeepSeq.html#v%3adeepseq)(or [$!!](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/deepseq-1.3.0.0/Control-DeepSeq.html#v%3a-36--33--33-)) for evaluating to normal form.